# Web scraping using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

I have a url:

```
test.com/Search/NumberSearch.aspx
```

On the page there are a number of controls, one of them is textbox. When the user enters a six digit (approximately) number into the textbox and hits enter, the page goes to another page:

```
test.com/Data/DetailsPage.aspx?mynum=123456
```

on that page there are a number of textboxes and other controls from which I need to scrape the data in addition to a number of links that I need to caputure in my code.

I have tried using VB.NET WebRequest:

```
Dim wreq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("test.com/Data/DetailsPage.aspx?mynum=" & num)
Dim wresp As HttpWebResponse = CType(wreq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)  
Dim dStream As Stream = wresp.GetResponseStream()
Dim rdr As New StreamReader(dStream)
Dim respStr As String = rdr.ReadToEnd()
```

As a result my respStr contains a string with html code but that code is for

```
 test.com/Search/NumberSearch.aspx
```

not for the resulting

```
test.com/Data/DetailsPage.aspx?mynum=123456
```

page with details.

My goal is to get the details page html programmatically.

I also tried using

```
WebClient.DownloadString
```

but gotten the same result. Can anyone help?

Comment: So if you use IE, FireFox, Chrom, etc... and enter the `test.com/Data/DetailsPage.aspx?mynum=` URL by hand, do you seen the results your looking for on the screen or do you see the `NumberSearch.aspx` page?

Comment: Also, does this site require you to logon in some manor prior to using it?

Comment: no, the site does not require any form of logon. I used both, Chrome and IE.  If I enter test.com/Data/DetailsPage.aspx?mynum= then I see NumberSearch.aspx

Comment: I wonder if you're missing some headers in your request.  Have you tried using a Debug Proxy tool like Fiddler to see what headers are past when using a web browser?

Comment: headers in my code? or on the page?

Comment: Headers in your code to request the page i.e. `wreq.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US")` or possibly `wreq.Accept =...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88410/discussion-between-jradich1234-and-elenadba).

Comment: I added the headers just as you suggested but it gave me same result - search page. Could it have something to do with the cookies?

Comment: Since you're doing a single request, you wouldn't have received any cookies at that point.

Comment: Headers are almost always the cause of problems like this.  I would start by setting the user agent, as that tends to be the things many sites key off of.

Comment: jradich1234, the problem did have something to do with cookie - I had to set Cookies property in the header and now it works

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the User-Agent header, as that is what many sites key off of:

```
Dim wreq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("test.com/Data/DetailsPage.aspx?mynum=" & num)
wreq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")

Dim wresp As HttpWebResponse = CType(wreq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim dStream As Stream = wresp.GetResponseStream()
Dim rdr As New StreamReader(dStream)
Dim respStr As String = rdr.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: John Koerner, the issue had to do with cookies