# Declaring variable as webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, variables, webbrowser-control

My doubt concerns the possibility of declaring a webbrowswer as a variable.

I am trying to code a windows form that will get a number from a mysql db, then insert this number in a website and then click on a button to submit it.

So far I've tried doing it declaring

```
Dim webb As New WebBrowser
```

, and then navigating it to the url, to then getElementById and SetAttribute to it, lastly invoking the "click" on the button.

**But my question is: I don't want the webbrowser to be displayed to the user in the windows form, I just want it to be on the code. So is it possible to just declare a variable As New Webbrowser?**

When I run my code I always get null references, I even tried to add document completed handlers but I started to wonder wether I am just declaring a variable that cant be declared.

Comment: Have you tried it before asking?

Comment: Quit beating yourself up, there is some question etiquette though and you'll want to try your best before submitting it here.  Not 100% but   [check out this example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class) and [on stackoverflow, web-scraping questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318404/web-scraping-using-vb-net)

Comment: `New` is not part of declaring a variable - `New` creates the instance.  Your question is vague, but it sounds like you want a form level variable (google SCOPE) and you want to declare it as `WithEvents` to be able to let the IDE create event handlers for you.